# Taking address of rvalue

Tags: c++, c++17, c++14, c++20

Why does GCC version >= `10.1` produces a `taking address of rvalue` error with the following code? Or, when using an lvalue instead, why does it spit out a `no matching function for call to 'a::n(a*)'` error? Where does the pointer parameter come from? Clang seems perfectly fine with accepting the code (and older GCC versions as well). Compiling with `-std=c++14` or `-std=c++17` results in the same behavior.

The [example code](https://godbolt.org/z/TdzT67frK):

```
struct a {
    constexpr auto n() const { return 3; }
    //
    // static constexpr auto n() { return 3; }    // ok
    // auto n() const { return 3; }               // ok
};

template<typename>
constexpr auto f() {
    int{a{}.n()};      // error
    //
    int(a{}.n());      // ok
    int x{a{}.n()};    // ok
}

constexpr auto g() {
    int{a{}.n()};      // ok
    int(a{}.n());      // ok
    int x{a{}.n()};    // ok
}
```

The error that is produced:

```
<source>: In function 'constexpr auto f()':
<source>:10:14: error: taking address of rvalue [-fpermissive]
   10 |     int{a{}.n()};      // error
      |         ~~~~~^~
<source>:10:14: error: no matching function for call to 'a::n(a*)'
<source>:2:20: note: candidate: 'constexpr auto a::n() const'
    2 |     constexpr auto n() const { return 3; }
      |                    ^
<source>:2:20: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
```

Comment: I don't see anything problematic with the code. Seems like a compiler bug to me.

Comment: @user4581301 My bad. When looking at it with fresh eyes, I see no problem with the question as it is. I removed my request for a MRE. It is already a MRE. Even [taking the rvalue part of the error out](https://godbolt.org/z/cqKqn1xa3) leaves the extremely confusing error `no matching function for call to 'a::n(a*)'` `candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided`.  - I believe that the `1 provided` part is `this` but find it tricky to figure out _why_. :-)

Comment: I submitted a [bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=104565)

Comment: @TedLyngmo This bug prevented us from migrating to GCC 10.3, which was quite unfortunate because GCC 10.3 provided a significant decrease in compile times. Thanks for taking the effort of submitting a bug report. Could you refer in the report to this post (with the URL field)?

Comment: @303 I updated the bug report with an URL to this question. Cheers!

Comment: Its status as a real bug now confirmed: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=104565 and my flimsical bug title was changed to _"[10/11/12 Regression] constexpr template goes wrong with class and call to constexpr method"_

Comment: It has now been fixed for gcc 12.

Answer (score 1):

As shown in the comment and gcc bugtracker ([Bugreport on gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=104565)) this is a compiler bug and has been fixed in gcc 12.